# How to populate 3 drop-down lists dynamically, using Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am filling **3 Dropdown lists**  using **Angular js** 
 
Based on the first drop-down selection, the second drop-down will fill, and based on the second drop-down third drop-down will fill.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select ng-model="option1" ng-options="option for option in options1" ng-change="getOptions2()">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="option2" ng-options="option for option in options2" ng-change="getOptions3()">
    </select>
    <select ng-model="option3" ng-options="option for option in options3">
    </select>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
var option1Options = ["Men", "Women", "Kids"];
var option2Options = [["Top wear","Bottom wear","Blazers"],
               ["W-Top Wear","W-Bottom Wear","W-Blazers"],
               ["K-Top wear","K-Bottom wear","K-others"]];
var option3Options = [["M-Tshirts","M-Casula Shirts","option2 - 3-3"],
               ["M-Jeans","option2 - 3-2","option2 - 3-3"],
               ["M-Blazers","option2 - 3-2","option2 - 3-3"],
               ["w-Tshirts","w-Casula Shirts","w-option2 - 3-3"]];

function myCtrl($scope){
    $scope.options1 = option1Options;
    $scope.options2 = []; 
    $scope.options3 = [];

    $scope.getOptions2 = function(){
        var key = $scope.options1.indexOf($scope.option1);
        var myNewOptions = option2Options[key];

        $scope.options2 = myNewOptions;
    };

    $scope.getOptions3 = function(){

        var key = $scope.options2.indexOf($scope.option2);
        var myNewOptions = option3Options[key];

        $scope.options3 = myNewOptions;
    };
}
```

**Fiddle Link** : http://jsfiddle.net/mayankBisht/Xku9z/513/

**Problem**

- When I am trying to fill third drop-down with women's options, it's still showing Mens options. 
  Please help.

Comment: it's not entirely clear how these 3 dropdowns relate to each other; you have 3 options in the first dropdown, which corresponds to 3 arrays in the second to choose from, but then 3 options in the second dropdown to select from 4 different arrays in the third dropdown?

Comment: you should consider re-mapping your options entirely, and creating objects with properties to select from, rather than arrays which have no direct relation to each other except their array order.

Comment: I think you need to set the third option according to the first option.if you want to show the last member of option3Options for women tell me to write this code.But consider recreating your array with more clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Your concept of binding dropdownlist is the problem here. you rather use array of object instead of normal array. You cannot make the mappings properly in this way.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided works for the first two levels. But here is a scenario where the third level fails.

You have specified 4 arrays in the 3rd level, but only 3 elements inside the individual arrays in the second level, thus the 4th array of the 3rd level is inaccessible.

Secondly for the first level you use the index of the element to get the respective list. But the problem is the 3rd level is complex. By that I mean.

If a user selects

`option1` -> `"Men"`

`option2` -> `"Bottom wear"`

The third level will be

`option3` -> `["M-Jeans","option2 - 3-2","option2 - 3-3"]`

Which is fine!

But take the below scenario.

`option1` -> `"Women"`

`option2` -> `"W-Bottom Wear"`

The third level will be

`option3` -> `["M-Jeans","option2 - 3-2","option2 - 3-3"]`

So you see the array needs to formatted differently for getting the different values.

I suggest you create an `array of objects` for this. Where we can lookup the key of that array and fetch the respective values for the same. Please check out the below snippet and let me know if you face any issues.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
var option1Options = ["Men", "Women", "Kids"];
var option2Options = [
  ["Top wear", "Bottom wear", "Blazers"],
  ["W-Top Wear", "W-Bottom Wear", "W-Blazers"],
  ["K-Top wear", "K-Bottom wear", "K-others"]
];
var option3Options = [{
  "Top wear": ["M-Tshirts", "M-Casula Shirts", "option2 - 3-3"]
}, {
  "Bottom wear": ["mens bottom wear here"]
}, {
  "Blazers": ["mens Blazers here"]
}, {
  "W-Top Wear": ["w-Tshirts", "w-Casula Shirts", "w-option2 - 3-3"]
}, {
  "W-Bottom Wear": ["womens bottom wear here"]
}, {
  "W-Blazers": ["womens blazers here"]
}, {
  "K-Top wear": ["K-Tshirts", "K-Casula Shirts", "option2 - 3-3"]
}, {
  "K-Bottom wear": ["kids bottom wear here"]
}, {
  "K-others": ["K-others here"]
}];
app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope) {
  $scope.options1 = option1Options;
  $scope.options2 = [];
  $scope.options3 = [];

  $scope.getOptions2 = function() {
    var key = $scope.options1.indexOf($scope.option1);
    var myNewOptions = option2Options[key];

    $scope.options2 = myNewOptions;
    $scope.options3 = [];
  };

  $scope.getOptions3 = function() {

    var myNewOptions = option3Options.filter(function(x) {
      return x[$scope.option2] !== undefined;
    })
    $scope.options3 = myNewOptions[0][$scope.option2];
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller='MyController' ng-app='myApp'>
  <select ng-model="option1" ng-options="option for option in options1" ng-change="getOptions2()">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="option2" ng-options="option for option in options2" ng-change="getOptions3()">
  </select>
  <select ng-model="option3" ng-options="option for option in options3">
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: @mayank Does this answer help you?